# Workflow with database create alter and drop commands and web applications in production

Tags: php, mysql, migration

At my work all production environments have limited mysql rights. For security all webapplications cannot execute mysql Create, Alter or Drop queries.

This leads us to a challenge. We have a SaaS software model. So our applications and databases grow grow every week. Tools like, doctrine migrations, phinx will help us through database migrations during the whole process. When we deploy (we use ansible for this) we have to ask our ops team to give all mysql accounts all privileges. After that we deploy and then they revoke privileges. I would like to get a rid of this dependency.

We have a special server where we could execute all queries that we would like to execute but there we don't have any application running. So no doctrine migrations or phinx files to execute. We could deploy our software there but we would only doing this for database migrations since phinx doesn't have an export feature.

Now I'll come down to my question. How are other companies doing this? Do we have a normal workflow? Could we improve our workflow and if yes then how?

I really can use some fresh ideas on this subject.

Comment: Can't the DDL statements be run by "root" (or some other admin login with ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*)?

Comment: Yes it can but not from the webserver. The mysqlcluster can only be reached from the webservers with limited rights.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem but I think it would be easy for you, when you deploy updates, to add in your deployment script something which will give all mysql accounts all privileges and then revoke them. And if your concern is about security, after the end of the deployment process you can just simply delete the script which contain root password.

Comment: Only our webusers have access to mysql from the webserver with limited rights so I can't change priviliges when logged in at the webserver. admin users can't connect from the webservers.

Mysql doesn't run on the webserver. We have different clusters. That makes it hard to migrate. This is also the reason why I'm wondering if we have a good workflow at all.

Sometimes I'm thinking: Wouldn't it be a better idea to create a virtual machine per customer, with a own mysql, own webserver. It also makes me wonder how other companies are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Create Stored Procedures.  Install them via root, have them use 'SECURITY DEFINER'.  Perform validation inside the SP, so that these routines do only what they should and only when they should.  Then give the API in the webserver EXECUTE privilege so they can execute the SPs.